# What should I buy to set up this Arduino wireless captors network?

Tags: arduino, xbee, zigbee

I want to make a Curling chronometer with 3 IR curtain barrier and 1 LCD display.

When the first barrier is cut, the (XBee) ZigBee module send a message to the ZigBee module on the LCD board the same for the two other captor.

After two messages, the LCD display the time between the two message.

I am not quite sure what I need to buy.

- 3x Arduino Uno
- 1x Arduino Mega ADK
- 4x Wireless shield SD (is it enough or should I add also a ZigBee module to plug on ?)
- 3 IR captor with 5meter range (Which captor since I should work on battery)
- 1 big 4 digits LCD display (Which LCD display so you can read it from 20m)

Actually there is 2 things : 
 - The research material I need to develop the concept with students in a lab
 - The production material to make a prototype which works on ice.

Thank you for your help,

Rémy

Comment: Shopping questions. It should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never want to buy whole Arduino dev boards for a project. Especially one needing "3x Arduino Uno". You need to look into replicating your circuit with just the microcontroller (Atmega328p) and the supporting circuitry.

Sparkfun sells Atmega chips with the Arduino bootloader [already burned onto them](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10524). From there you are going to want to learn to put your Arduino [project on a breadboard](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/Standalone). Here are some other links on breadboard Arduino:

1. [Standalone Arduino](http://arduino.cc/playground/Learning/Standalone)
2. [Instructables Standalone](http://www.instructables.com/id/Standalone-Arduino-ATMega-chip-on-breadboard/)

The next amount of general advice I would give you is to revise your project to the fewest number of parts. I don't think you need an entire microcontroller for every IR "curtain". Always try to employ the KISS principle.